# Multiple 'having' clauses blows up Rails 3 / Arel

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I think I've found a bug in Rails 3 / Arel, but I'm hoping someone can clarify my problem before I try and fix it and/or submit a bug report.

- On a very simple app, with a Question model: (submitter_id: integer, option_count: integer)

The code that I'm using:

```
q = Question.where(:submitter_id => 1)
q = q.having(['option_sum > ?', 5])
q = q.having(['option_sum < ?', 10])
q = q.select("#{Question.table_name}.*, MAX(#{Question.table_name}.option_count) AS option_sum")
q.to_sql
q
```

This blows up with:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/arel-f092ae544f58/lib/arel/select_manager.rb:94:in `having'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/rails-76053fe4d12b/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:193:in `build_arel'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/rails-76053fe4d12b/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:162:in `arel'
```

Taking out one of the 'having' clauses fixes the issue, and generates the proper SQL.

Any comments would be appreciated. Arel and Rails 3 are edge versions, with revisions as listed in the error above.

Comment: Wouldn't this be best as a bug on lighthouse? (with a test ofcourse)

Comment: Brady, did you find a satisfactory answer to this problem? I'm still running into it and the combine into one having method isn't looking terribly helpful in my situation.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, no. But GearHead's solution worked for me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive testing, this looks like a Rails bug after all, although I haven't been able to confirm it. This problem occurs on a minimal test Rails app as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Arel gives similar error, when scope operators are not in SQL-like order, for example try to invoke select("..") before havings. Also, I'm not sure, that multiple havings are allowed in such requests, so try 
q = q.having(['(option_sum > ? AND option_sum < ?)', 5, 10])

Comment: Thanks Gearhead, but multiple HAVINGs are definitely allowed by spec, and the Rails 3 source looks like it should be allowed (that particular part of the code uses a '+=' to append to the 'having' array). Alternatively, is there a nice way to merge multiple havings calls into one, as you've written? These are generated programmatically, so can't just write it the way you have.

Comment: Did you try to call .select and .group before calling .having? Arel scopes are state-controlled, for example you can not invoke .offset before .limit in some DB drivers.

Comment: Also, the most simple way for merging havings as I see: join each next condition to the string and append a parameter to the end of array, like that: ['field_1 > ?', x1] -> ['field_1 > ? AND field_2 < ?', x1, x2] -> ['field_1 > ? AND field_2 < ? AND field_3 = ?', x1, x2, x3], and so on. then call just one having